# Alternative to Paperwork

Tags: alternative, ocr

I am looking for an alternative to the program Paperwork as it is rather complicated to install under Ubuntu. I am specifically interested in finding a way to read dates, prices and other details from scanned invoices and store everything in a kind of database or at least Excel sheet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't find a program called `paperwork` could you provide a link? and as what the exact problem is when installing?

Comment: Are you searching for an `Optical Character Recognition` alternative?

Comment: For alternatives, see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OCR

Comment: If that is what you wanted, let me know, so i can post it as an answer

Comment: Here is a link: https://github.com/jflesch/paperwork

Comment: Basically, what I am looking for is a program which I can give my about 1000 scanned invoices. The program should read out the date of the invoice, the price of the product and a few buzz words. After that it should give me a kind of database in which I can sort and search for stuff.